# Where is the easiest spot(s) to get DFA kills?

Tags: achievements, saints-row-iv

I am trying to get the DFA (Death From Above) kills achievement for SR4.

I think the best spot for other superpower/weapon kill grinding is in E.T.D. DLC, mission 2 specifically. However, the DFA superpower is not available during that mission.

What is the best (selection criteria = most kills per second, ease of setup, possibly repeatable) spot(s) to grind out the DFA kills achievement/challenge?  I am near the end of the game, so using non-repeatable missions are not preferred, but I am still interested in knowing about them.

Comment: One of my favorite spots is super power fight club, the hard variant.  I think the second wave is just infinite guys who try to get in close.  I don't know if these guys count, but you might give it a try to see.  Just quit the activity or finish it before time runs out, I think failing will cause you to lose progress.

Comment: @agent86 I know that failing will reset progress on super fight club. I will have to try quitting early, but so far the fight clubs have been my best source.

Comment: The other thing I'd try if that doesn't work is starting a mayhem.  I think you can get a decent amount of alien kills and/or go to the military base and get some good kills there.  It's been a little while, though.

Comment: @agent86 the hard fight club was the best place of all I tried. got around 40 kills there per run (7 minutes each). If you want to write up an answer I will accept it. Otherwise, I will just answer it myself in a day or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing almost all of the "kills with powers" challenges, the best place is the hard variant of Super Power Fight Club.  As is my way, I [have a complete guide to challenges and related achievements for your perusal](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/saints-row-4-challengesachievements-guide/):

> The best way to get aliens to kill with super powers is… to play Super Power Fight Club. If you play the “Hard” instance of this, the second wave is “King of the Hill.” An infinite number of gang members with baseball bats will spawn. These guys count as Aliens for the purposes of your challenges! Just don’t capture the hill – fight the infinite gang members with your powers instead.

Failing the event will reset any challenge progress, so make sure you win before time runs out.  I've also had luck in the past quitting out of the event before it ends, but that's a bit riskier.